# docker build with Dockerfile, but the image has no name or tag

Tags: docker, docker-build, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I installed **Docker desktop for mac**. The version is `1.12.0-rc4-beta19`

when I use `docker build -t self/centos:java8 .`

the image has no name or tag

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              1581ffcbfd7f        5 minutes ago       196.8 MB
```

What is wrong with the build command?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

is your image building correctly? the name does not get set when there is an error in the build. This because every step in the build is a new image created and with an error you won't get to the last step with the correctly named image

btw you can set it manually with the tag command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/

Comment: thanks, You are right !The error happened, there is a connection refused

Comment: how to know if there is an error while building up? for me it is showing `Successfully built` but shows <none>:<none>

Comment: @Vishrant, in general you can see the build output (and don't use `-q` or `--quiet`).

Comment: I am getting a successfull built and if i immediately run docker run command i see the name but some how after sometime the name is getting set to none. can someone please help?

Comment: This solved my problem. If your build ends in something like `Running in e3e4cc0a2264` then it means that your docker image hasn't finished building because there's a command that is "hanging" (in my case a python script that hadn't finished).

Answer (score 12):

Tag an image referenced by ID
To tag a local image with ID “0e5574283393” into the “fedora” repository with “version1.0”:

`docker tag 0e5574283393 ExampleApps/myapp:version1.0`

Answer (score 2):

I know it's years later, but people still find this question via search and here's another reason for that error.

I mistakenly reused a build command without changing the tag parameter. It appears that the new build will take the tag, and the old one will switch to the double none.

Answer (score 1):

I was also confused. I always had the image with the name .  Until I looked at the error message. A big thank you here to **@Zeromus**.

```
Step 4/8 : COPY package*.json ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

That was the error for me. I accidentally had my Dockerfile in the wrong folder. Ok, I'm sure this doesn't happen to many people, but for those who are also wondering. It can be a possible error.

Otherwise, if it happens: it's an **error in your Dockerfile**.